# Mixed authentication in ASP.NET 4.5 website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

I want to do mixed authentication in a ASP.NET website.

The current WPF application has the following login process:
a) retrieve the current windows user and compare the sid with all sids stored in datebase => if the sid exists, the user is found and logged in
b) when a) fails => show a login form and do forms authentication

Now he wants this process in the ASP.NET migration of the product. But I cannot get the local user's SID at the server.
Furthermore the website has to run as on-premise on a webserver within the domain/lan and as well on azure.

Any recommendations ho to achive this best?

I successfully implemented the forms-part, but the NT-login thing seems not to be possible. I found the part of a possible solution here (http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/), bit I don't think this will work due to the "user is not authenticated when SID doesn't exist" and the Azure-thing.